# Java - Maven - Reusing Entity layer at both client and server side projects

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot, Hibernate, Thymeleaf project, I'm a bit confused to achieve the best architecture to reuse my entity layer.

I have 2 Maven parent projects, I want to achieve the below project hierarchy with just creating one ProjectEntity (reusing it in both parents)

1. ProjectAPIParent

   a) ProjectEntity

   b) ProjectRepository

   c) ProjectAPI
2. ProjectClientUIParent

   a) ProjectEntity

   b) ProjectClientUI

The problem is one child project cannot have multiple parents.

Now, I have an option of creating one base parent project only but the problem is that it doesn't sound right because I want full loose coupling between client side and the server side projects.

What would you suggest me to do in this case?

Your opinion will matter a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: Making the `ProjectEntity` a library and use it in both is not an option?

Comment: Making it as a library is hard to maintain because I have to separately run maven package or maven install command for this project after every change in the code of this project.

Comment: I see, maybe using tools like Jenkins can help you in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really an idiomatic rule to take this kind of decision.

**Personally**, I select as parent of an artifact, the project that manifests the strongest natural ownership relationship with.

For example if the `ProjectEntity` source code is designed to be modified only by developers of the `ProjectAPIParent` project and released with, `ProjectAPIParent` should be very probably the Maven  parent (as well as its aggregrator pom) of the  `ProjectEntity` module.  And `ProjectClientUIParent` should so use  `ProjectEntity` as a dependency.

But if you don't manage to identify clearly a parent project that owns such a relationship with this artifact, you should probably not make `ProjectEntity` a children of none of them.
In this case, making `ProjectEntity` a dependency of this two projects makes more sense.

---

As a side note, whatever your choice for the parent pom, you may define `ProjectEntity` as Maven modules (to not mix up with Maven children) in the aggregrator pom.xml of `ProjectAPIParent` and `ProjectClientUIParent`.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Waiting for more answers, probably that might change my opinion.

Comment: You are right. Other opinions could be interesting.*

Comment: Re "_source code is designed to be modified only by_" – How does a (usual) build  modify source code (apart from resource filtering or the like)?

Comment: @Gerold Broser  You are right. It is not clear.  "by developers of the `ProjectAPIParent` project " is more clear.

Comment: @davidxxx After looking at these answers, I think keeping ProjectEntity as a child just in ProjectAPIParent and adding ProjectEntity dependency in ProjectClientUIParent makes sense to me. But as per reading your comment, I feel you suggest that Gerold's answer is better. I'm looking out for your unbiased view on this, please. :)

Comment: @Siddharth Sachdeva  It is the choice that I would also make to prevent a strong coupling between all projects. About Gerold's answer, in other contexts it may be very fine but objectively it doesn't address your requirements.

Comment: @davidxxx As per the question asked, I'm going to accept your answer that obviously right as per the requirement of the question, however, for knowledge purpose only, Gerold's architecture design is suitable/better? Maybe I'm going wrong with the concept of loose coupling here?

Comment: @Siddharth Sachdeva  You are not wrong at all. Without any requirement, I would do the loose coupling way. After, it is an opinion question. I express my mind in this last comment :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629984/java-maven-reusing-entity-layer-at-both-client-and-server-side-projects/48630474?noredirect=1#comment84281176_48631677

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: @davidxxx I followed the architecture you suggested, now I deployed ProjectAPIParent as a separate application on Heroku and ProjectClientUI (which has ProjectEntity dependency) on Heroku separately, now, the problem is ProjectClientUI is unable to resolve ProjectEntity dependency. What best would you suggest me to do in this situation, please? Thanks

Comment: "the problem is ProjectClientUI is unable to resolve ProjectEntity dependency." What do you mean by that exactly ? What is your exact issue ? If the dependency is packaged in the ProjectClientUI component (jar I assume) you should have no issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could establish the following:

```
+- ApplicationParent
   +- APIParent
   |  +- ProjectAPI
   |  +- Repository
   +- ClientUIParent
   |  +- ClientUI
   +- Entity
```

`ApplicationParent` POM:

```
<modules>
  <module>APIParent</module>
  <module>ClientUIParent</module>
</modules>
```

`APIParent` POM:

```
<modules>
  <module>../Entity</module>
  <module>Repository</module>
  <module>ProjectAPI</module>
</modules>
```

`ClientUIParent` POM:

```
<modules>
  <module>../Entity</module>
  <module>ClientUI</module>
</modules>
```

Such you can:

- build your application as a whole (via `ApplicationParent`)
- build `APIParent` and `ClientUIParent` individually

  You will have to take care, of course, that `APIParent` and `ClientUIParent` don't build individually at the same time locally.
- declare things common to all (e.g. JUnit dependency) just *once*, in `ApplicationParent`
- use [`<dependencyManagment>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) to declare dependency details for *all* dependencies used in any of the sub-projects just *once*
- separate declarations necessary for certain sub-projects only across the individual POMs

Comment: Your answer is interesting and makes sense in modules that we want to integrate in a single root. But the OP wants to avoid the coupling between the two big projects : "Now, I have an option of creating one base parent project only but the problem is that it doesn't sound right because I want full loose coupling between client side and the server side projects."

Comment: @davidxxx I know the term _loose coupling_ more from source code itself and its inter-dependencies therein rather than from build environments. However, `APIParent` and `ClientUIParent` _are_ (extremely) loosely coupled. In fact, they are _not coupled at all_. They are individual projects. None of them knows anything about the other – build-wise (apart from possible dependencies which are not stated in the question). The only one who knows both of them is their common parent `ApplicationParent`. That's how it should be, shouldn't it?

Comment: I need to understand a thing that is not clear. Is the `ApplicationParent` module both an aggregator and parent pom ?  As you said : "declare things common to all (e.g. JUnit) just once, in `ApplicationParent`"  it would mean that `ApplicationParent` is both. In this case, it creates a stronger coupling.

Comment: @davidxxx Yes, it's both (hence the `<modules>` in its POM). I think I know what you mean. Do you compare it to e.g. Java's class hierarchy, where a superclass doesn't even know about the existence of a subclass? Well, this is not a development environment, it's a build environment. How would you otherwise achieve to build the application as a whole if the aggregator `ApplicationParent` doesn't know its components?

Comment: @davidxxx  I worked as release manager (including the complete build environment management) with such a structure in a large project (~150 devs across 4 countries, 25 first-level projects + 3 levels of sub-projects in almost each of them, a few 10^5 LOC) for a few years. And it worked very well.

Comment: The `<modules>` presence means that it is an aggregator pom. We can know that a pom is a  parent pom only if the child pom defines it as parent in the `<parent>` element. Yes, we can compare it to the superclass that knows its children. Whatever, build or source code, the question of the coupling may matter.  To build the application as a whole, you could define `ApplicationParent` as aggregator **only** and **not** as parent pom. In this way, you create a low coupling : only for builds, not for dependencies.

Comment: I didn't tell that it will not work :)  I tell only that the way to favor depends on the requirements.

Comment: I will sleep. We could go on tomorrow with pleasure. You have my vote anyway.

Comment: @davidxxx OK, but how do you centralize, i.e. minimize, configuration then? From my POV one of the big advantages of Maven is that a POM can be both. Otherwise, if you skip the parent (and inheritance) part, you would have to declare (and maintain!) identical declarations over and over again in each sub-project. I'm sure you know DRY.

Comment: @davidxxx And if we stick to the class hierarchy idiom there's basically no difference: subclasses use `extends` and/or `implements`, sub-projects use `<parent>`. Things that are exposed by the superclass are known by the subclass, the same applies to parent/sub-projects. Do you know a build tool that supports DI and/or a SOA application server lurking in the background? I don't even want to know one. Maven with its purely hierarchical concept(s) is tough enough to master. :)

Comment: In fact, coupling distinct applicative projects to a single parent pom that defines many things has one advantage (configuration out of the box) but has also an important drawback : adding specific dependencies or upgrading some defined versions may fast become complicated and error prone. Forcing all projects to use the same parent pom that define many things may hurt the projects capacity to adapt themselves to changes. Besides, it forces maintainers of the base parent pom to perform very exhaustive tests before each release to prevent regressions for user projects.

Comment: Personally, to minimize configuration, instead, I strongly encourage to use Spring Boot and its starters (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html)

Comment: Thanks, Gerold, I learnt a lot from your answer. my vote up for your answer.